# how to show loading image while ajax function in process?

Tags: jquery, ajax, progress-bar

Following is my ajax function which will fill the html div on  button click..now what i want is how can i show loader image when this function starts and after this function exucte the loader will hide.

```
function campaignList(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'<%=campaignListURL.toString()%>',
            data:{},
            success:function(data){
                $(".main_content").html(data);                              
            }
        });
    }
```

I had tried with following script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#loading_layer").ajaxStart(function(){
       $(this).show();
     });
</script>
```

but nothing happens..
following is my div where the ajax loader gif image is there which i want to hide and show

```
<div id="loading_layer" style="display: none">
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Above was for ajx method i was asking..but if i want to do same thing while form is submitting then how can i achieve this..?

following is my code line of one javascript which submitt the form

{some javascript code for form validation if all validation true then flag will be true.....

```
   if (flag == true) {
    div.style.display = '';
 alert("");
    document.editadform.submit();
    }
         div.style.display = 'none';
        return flag;
```

}

following is my one div that haev img which i want to show hide on submition of form and when its done i want to hide

" />

so any one can guide me about this problem?

Comment: How do  you think`$.ajax` would know about `ajaxStart`?

Comment: i just read somewhere that Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent, jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none are in progress, jQuery triggers the ajaxStart event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxStart() method are executed at

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should just work fine:

```
function campaignList(){
        $(".main_content").html("<img src='loader.png'>"); // show the ajax loader
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'<%=campaignListURL.toString()%>',
            data:{},
            success:function(data){
                $(".main_content").html(data);  // this will hide the loader and replace it with the data                            
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: thnx its very simple way u guide me..i understood //but my problem is how can i give img source relatively..i am using liferay i dont have any vast knowledge about jquery but my src will come like this "request.getcontextpath"/img/loader.png" so how can i put this way in src of img?

Comment: well, one way you can do this is by making a global variable that will hold the value for "request.getcontextpath"/img/loader.png at the beginning and just add it to the $(".main_content") object

Comment: i done that..thanx...now what happen is ..image just shows for glance..hardly for one millisecond..is there any way to make it show proper?

Comment: I guess the request gets completed in a millisecond so it hides.

Comment: ok.by the way thanx for this...a simple and in few second u solved my problem

Comment: hey need your help..please see my updated question..i have to use same thing while post method but having some issue

Answer (score 9):

You can do by adding `beforeSend` in your AJAX script,

Take a look at jquery Ajax doc, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
function campaignList(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'<%=campaignListURL.toString()%>',
            data:{},
            beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
               //Add your image loader here
            },
            success:function(data){
                $(".main_content").html(data);                              
            }
        });       

 }
```